# Validate form before submit with jQuery post to javaScript then to confirmation page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I need to validate a form using jQuery then submit it to a JavaScript file that redirects it to the confirmation/send mail page. The reason I am doing this is to prevent spam emails with out putting some type of Captcha in. I am basically putting in a wrong url for the post to page of the form and then changing that to the correct page in an external JavaScript file. Everything works great except the form submits before it validates. I can see it mark the errors for a slight second before it submits.

Validation JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#contactform').submit(function() {
      return $('#contactform').valid();
    });

        $("#contactform").validate();

            $("#Name").rules("add", {
        required: true,
        minlength: 5,
        messages: {
        required: "Required",
        minlength: jQuery.format("Minimum {0} Characters Required")
     }   
    }); 
        $("#Question").rules("add", {
        required: true,
        minlength: 20,
        messages: {
        required: "Required",
        minlength: jQuery.format("Question Must Be {0} Character Long")
     }

    });

    $("#math").rules("add", {
        required: true,
        equalTo: "#math2",
        messages: {
        required: "Solve Security Question.",
     }
    });


});
</script>
```

External JS Redirect:

```
function submitCommentForm() {
    // Change the form action to the real submission page
    document.getElementById('contactform').action = "confirmation.php";
    // Submit the form
    document.getElementById('contactform').submit();
}
```

Comment: There are better ways to stop spammers from making submissions than what you are doing. Are you ok with the fact your approach (if it was working) would also make it so that users with Javascript disabled would be unable to submit the form?

Comment: yes I am aware that none js users would not be able to submit the form. What are the better ways? I have been using the jquery validation for the past couple years and received no spam until a few days ago.

Comment: Do a search for "honeypot" within this site and you will find a couple of questions that might help you. I have implemented them many times in forms with spam problems and have had good success with them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
$('#contactform').submit(function() {
  return $('#contactform').valid();
});
```

To

```
$('#contactform').submit(function() {
  if($(this).valid()){
    submitCommentForm();
  }else{
    alert('Please fix the errors within the form.');
  }
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a jQuery plugin to validate form data.

This is a good one -> [Ketchup](http://demos.usejquery.com/ketchup-plugin/)